# Output: "[Warning] Could not find workspace while activating"

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error when opening VS Code. Does anyone know what it means? I've done some research but didn't get any relevant information :(
I've tried creating a workflow to see if the error disappeared, but it didn't.
It seems that react native is asking for a workspace to start but is it asking that in the first place? Can I disable react native from running when opening VS Code?

[image]

The folder opened when the screenshot above was taken was the folder it opens by default, I believe it's the mac "home" personal folder, and I have a folder called "git" inside of it, with all projects.

Answer (score 4):

Given the date of this posting (2023-02-07), you're probably on version 1.10.0 of the extension. This sounds like this bug report in the `microsoft/vscode-react-native` GitHub repo: [[Bug] Extension activating when it shouldn't #1891](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1891).

[The fix has been made available in version 1.10.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/1891#issuecomment-1461507415).

Also, note from the extension's readme documentation:

> Before going any further make sure that you:
>
> - [have a working React Native environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).
> - have the [`emulator`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) utility available in your `PATH` if you're developing Android applications.
> - [...]

Answer (score 1):

Got it, this annoying log came from React Native Tools extension. They specify the requirements in the docs:

[image: Extension docs]

In my case, I don't have a specific React Native environment or the emulator PATH is not right.